# How to fix overlapping div elements?

Tags: html, css

When minimizing the window, two `<div>` elements overlap.
How can I fix it?

```css
#pageName {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#toAddress {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#fromAddress {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
#from {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#des {
  width: 730px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  font-style: italic;
}
#mainContent {
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#tblContent {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#tblContent td,
#tblContent th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageName">
  URGENT REQUEST FOR SECURITY CHECK
</div>
<div id="toAddress">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>To:</td>
      <td id="toName">ABBEY NATIONAL PLC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fax:</td>
      <td id="toFax">Uknown</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date:</td>
      <td>04 Jun 2001 10:30:21</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="fromAddress">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="from">From:</td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Acquirung Bank</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Risk Management</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>100 Bond Street</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>London</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>W1</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fax:</td>
      <td id="fromFax">0207 234567890/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tel:</td>
      <td id="fromTel">0207 123456789/</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="des">
  The transaction/authorization detailed below, have been identified by RiskNet as suspicious activity for the merchant. Could you please check the status of the cards and if the values are not normal spending, could you please contact the cardholder to
  verify the transaction.
  <br />Test
</div>

<div id="mainContent">
  <span id="text">
            Please fax a response by return
        </span>

  <table id="tblContent">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Cardholder Number</th>
        <th>Ccy</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Trans Date</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Our Reference</th>
        <th>MCC</th>
        <th>Retailer NameTown</th>
        <th>Normal</br>Spending?</th>
        <th>Cardholder</br>Contacted</th>
        <th>Response</th>
        <th>Does Customer</br>Have Card?</th>
        <th>Goods</br>Recieved?</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>1234567890123451</td>
      <td>GBP</td>
      <td>125.78</td>
      <td>24 May 2001</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>1254151822928</td>
      <td>3391</td>
      <td>PICK N MIX, MANCHETER</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>Genuine/Fraud</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1234567890123451</td>
      <td>GBP</td>
      <td>27.60</td>
      <td>23 May 2001</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>1254151822929</td>
      <td>3391</td>
      <td>PICK N MIX, MANCHETER</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>Genuine/Fraud</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1234567890123451</td>
      <td>GBP</td>
      <td>435.70</td>
      <td>22 May 2001</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>100131014426</td>
      <td>5193</td>
      <td>MECHANICS ANONYMOUS, LONDON</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>Genuine/Fraud</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1234567890123451</td>
      <td>GBP</td>
      <td>72.16</td>
      <td>21 May 2001</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>100131014427</td>
      <td>5193</td>
      <td>MECHANICS ANONYMOUS, LONDON</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>Genuine/Fraud</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1234567890123451</td>
      <td>GBP</td>
      <td>259.75</td>
      <td>21 May 2001</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>1254151822930</td>
      <td>3391</td>
      <td>PICK N MIX, MANCHETER</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>Genuine/Fraud</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1234567890123451</td>
      <td>GBP</td>
      <td>509.84</td>
      <td>24 May 2001</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>1254151822931</td>
      <td>3391</td>
      <td>PICK N MIX, MANCHETER</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>Genuine/Fraud</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1234567890123451</td>
      <td>GBP</td>
      <td>46.43</td>
      <td>24 May 2001</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>1254151822932</td>
      <td>3391</td>
      <td>PICK N MIX, MANCHETER</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>Genuine/Fraud</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
      <td>YES/NO</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[View on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmPPeO)

Comment: Does `position:fixed;` on your `#des` element rings any bells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to prevent the window from getting that small and allowing an overlap.

You could add the following CSS:

```
html, body {
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

See the [CodePen fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpJJmE).

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is create a parent DIV for these #toAdress and #fromAdress DIVs and use this little [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) to this newly created parent div. It's a very common issue with floated items... So it may look like

```
<div class="cf">
    <div id="toAdress">... your content ...</div>
    <div id="fromAdress">... your content ...</div>
</div>

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```